# Unity - Coroutine in the NetworkLobbyManager stops by itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have extended the NetworkLobbyManager of the unity assests. I added a coroutine

```
 IEnumerator CheckIPAddressAvailability(){
      while (LobbyDiscovery.singleton.networkIpAddr == "") {
           Debug.Log ("While : " + LobbyDiscovery.singleton.networkIpAddr);
           yield return null;
      }
       gotIpAddr ();
 }
```

This coroutine is started on click of the client join button. It basically waits till the broadcasted IP address of host has been received by the client. But it runs only once and stops abruptly.

So, when I start the coroutine on click of 'Join' button, then it runs only once.But when I start the coroutine at the start of the LobbyMainMenu script it runs multiple times untill I click the 'Join' button. So, basically I get multiple Debugs of "While: " (I dont't get the IP address. It does not run long enough for that). Also, I don't get any errors.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What do you get in the console?

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to add that in the question. One sec

Comment: Shouldn't the gotIpAddr (); statement inside the while loop after the yield statement?

Comment: should it? I doubt that. Anyways I tried it but still get the same output @ZayedUpal

Comment: I get just one Debug "While : " in the console and no errors @Lece

Comment: Sounds OK. Try moving the Debug.Log call to the line after the loop. That string must be setting to something (perhaps white-space, if nothing else)??

Comment: Add a `null` check as well to `LobbyDiscovery.singleton.networkIpAddr`. Like this `(while (LobbyDiscovery.singleton.networkIpAddr == "") || LobbyDiscovery.singleton.networkIpAddr == null)`